# Overriding an Attribute with its NonNullable Version

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to define a type that takes another type and one of it's keys and overrides that key by it' non nullable version. So far I came up with this.

```
type WithAttributeDefined<T, Key extends keyof T> = T & {[Key]: NonNullable<T[Key]>}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

```
interface Foo {
    foo?: string
}

//  v-- error
let x: WithAttributeDefined<Foo, "foo"> = {foo: "foo"}
```

It complains that the literal is missing a member `"[unknown]"` with type `NonNullable<Foo["foo"]>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type WithAttributeDefined<T, K extends keyof T> = T &
  Record<K, Exclude<T[K], null | undefined>>;
```